# Do functors that send direct sums to tensor products have a name?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose a category $C$ is given with direct sums and tensor products, and let $F:C\to C$ be a functor with the property that $F(A\oplus B)\cong F(A)\otimes F(B)$. It would be tempting to call $F$ an *exponential* functor.

Does $F$ have a largely accepted qualifying term that expresses the above property?

Comment: Well, '(strict) monoidal functor' from the monoidal category $(C,\oplus)$ to $(C,\otimes)$..

Comment: That equals sign is no good; you should of course ask for a canonical isomorphism (which then needs to satisfy an axiom). This is already an issue for, say, the symmetric algebra functor from vector spaces to itself. It is just not true that $\text{Sym}(V \oplus W)$ is literally equal to $\text{Sym}(V) \otimes \text{Sym}(W)$, whatever that means...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ah that's right thanks! I'll fix that

Comment: That's still not right. Being monoidal is not a *property* of a functor, it's a *structure*. You need to pick a family of isomorphisms $\eta_{A, B} : F(A \oplus B) \cong F(A) \otimes F(B)$, and that family of isomorphisms itself needs to satisfy some extra axioms (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+functor). In particular, a given functor can have more than one monoidal structure, even up to isomorphism.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm ok with assuming extra structure whenever needed in order to name the functor, so in this case I'm happy to assume such isomorphisms exist and that the axiom they must satisfy hold.

Comment: In that case, as Berci says, $F$ is a monoidal functor with respect to two different monoidal structures on $F$. "Exponential functor" is probably a fine term.

Comment: Great! Many thanks, both! I wish I knew more about category theory, but it is not my field really :)

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call that 'exponential functor', I think this name is already used for something else..